# How to sum up values of different keys in a list of maps in Elixir

Tags: elixir, reduce

Hello i want to sum up all **count** and all **val** keys, to a new map which contains the accumulated values of both keys.

This is what i've done so far:

```
list = [
  %{count: 1, val: 12},
  %{count: 3, val: 7},
  %{count: 1, val: 5},
  %{count: 2, val: 3},
  %{count: 2, val: 5},
  %{count: 1, val: 3}
]

x = &%{count: &1, val: &1}
sumCount = list |> Enum.reduce(0, &(&1.count + &2)) |> x.() |> IO.inspect()
```

I get this result:

```
#ouput: 
%{count: 10, val: 10}
```

But I need this result:

```
%{count: 10, val: 35}
```

I just know how to sum up just one key. Should I sum up the keys seperately in two functions? I think thats not performant, considering the list will have even more values/maps or maybe some more keys.
Is there a efficient way to sum up all the keys at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.reduce/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/2), because your list elements and accumulated value are the same format. The trick is to use the entire map `%{count: count, val: val}` as the accumulator, rather than just a single integer:

```elixir
Enum.reduce(list, fn item, acc ->
  %{count: item.count + acc.count, val: item.val + acc.val}
end)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you're looking for?

```
Enum.reduce(list, %{count: 0, val: 0}, fn %{count: count, val: val}, acc ->
  %{count: acc.count + count, val: acc.val + val}
end)
```

Comment: The initial accumulator is redundant here, use [`Enum.reduce/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/2) instead.

Comment: Yes, but I think it depends if you need to handle the empty case, in which case `reduce/2` can't infer the initial accumulator? (`Raises Enum.EmptyError if enumerable is empty.`)

Answer (score 5):

I would go with reducing the initial list by [`Map.merge/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html?#merge/3)

```rb
Enum.reduce(list, &Map.merge(&1, &2, fn _, v1, v2 -> v1 + v2 end))
#⇒ %{count: 10, val: 35}
```

Comment: Using merge conflict resolution is hardly simpler than just summing the values.

Comment: It’s shorter, easier extendable to the case of 100 keys, and does not depend on keys names, hence easier to refactor. Enough reasons to vote for it.